# Fast way to access a webbrowser from multiple locations

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

**Situation**
I have a webbrowser, usually with about 6 to 8 tabs open. If I close the browser and reopen it, I can continue where I left off.

The browser I have open needs to be accessible from multiple locations.

Due to the nature of what are in the tabs, I need to password protect its access.
I have other apps that fall under this category too, such as an email client. It may be possible to do something on app level. If that's the case, just focus on the webbrowser.

**What I have now**
I have setup a server where I can RDP into. It runs windows 10 and I've used a password protected user to prevent unintended access. There are other users who work on this machine too, but none at the same time.

My problem is that it takes some time for logging into the account before I can start working in the browser. A fresh login can take up to 50 seconds before I can start using the browser. Keeping the session open and just disconnecting works, but with many users connecting, it takes system resources, which eventually means I have to reboot the pc to make it fast again.

I'm using Vivaldi (chrome based browser) but can switch if a solution works in another browser, but not vivaldi.

**What I'm looking for**
I'm looking for a way to make this work. Its possible RDP is already the best option. In that case, I'd like to know if there is any way I can make changes for this to work much better. I'm considering installing Windows Server 2016 as replacement, but I'm not sure if it will be sufficient. I will also be watching videos in the environment (youtube, etc) and it works very well in my Windows 10 environment, not sure if it still will in windows server 2016.

Comment: As you don't really have any description on what browser you're using or why RDP is actually insufficient it's not really possible to answer. Some browsers offer sync mechanisms across multiple instances, others don't. You could use a server profile and store the browser profile within it but that would not work (necessarily) work if you're using mobile devices etc.

Comment: @Seth thanks for your comment. I'll edit in the necessary information, though syncing across devices is not something I want to do. The information is too sensitive for that. I did state why RDP is insufficient. It is not, but the loading times are long. I'd like to be able to get to my browser faster. If I'm not logged in, it takes about 30 seconds for the desktop environment to load, then another 20 seconds for the browser to start. I use Windows 10 with Oracle VM on it, no SSD unfortunately, with a windows 10 virtualised inside. It has 16 GB of ram of which 8 dedicated to the guest.